# $(".scrollable").scrollable is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I am getting the error : $(".scrollable").scrollable is not a function when I attempt to use the scrollable

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(function() {
  // initialize scrollable with mousewheel support
  $(".scrollable").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what is causing this?

**[Edit]**

After Mark Hildreth pointed out that the library I was using already bundles jQuery, I removed my Google jQuery CDN reference (not shown above), and then I got the '$ is not a function' error.

I knew then that jQuery was clashing with flowplay, so I updated my pages to use

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function()){
   // jQuery('#foo) .... etc
});
```

This is mildly annoying, as I have to change the script in my existing pages to use jQuery instead of $.

Is there anyway I can continue to  use $, or do I HAVE to use jQuery ?

Comment: Running this exact code causes 0 errors. What else is going on in your script?

Comment: I've also tested this and did not receive errors.

Comment: same here. Can you provide more info? Maybe try Ctr + f5 in case cache is corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

```
// you don't have to use jQuery(document).ready(function()){});
// or noConflict

$ = null; // doean't matter here what happens to $

// just wrap your jQuery code passing in jQuery...
(function ($) {
    //write jQuery here...
    $(".scrollable").scrollable({
        vertical: true,
        mousewheel: true
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are including http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js in your code then you need to write jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I think that you are missing the jQuery library. You can include it from google cdn.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

source:
http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: I don't think this it the problem. It appears that the jquery tools library doesn't work like a plugin where you need the jquery library included seperately. See the [http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html](download page) for that library.

Comment: Sorry, f'd up the formatting and can't change: [download page](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    var $j=jQuery.noConflict();
```

Since javascript also uses $ symbol, conflicts arise. Then you can write the code as follows

```
    $j(document).ready(function()){
    // jQuery('#foo) .... etc
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question - can he do it without changing his `$` reference everywhere?